# Change JAVA_HOME variable in mac os for ionic

Tags: java, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have made changes by using below command to set JAVA_HOME

```
rajendras-mbp:demo username$ /usr/libexec/java_home 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home
rajendras-mbp:demo username$ export JAVA_HOME="`/usr/libexec/java_home -v '1.8*'`"
rajendras-mbp:demo username$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_161"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)
```

It sets JDK 1.8 when i checked java version

But after i hit the `ionic cordova run android` it's throwing below error

```
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home
(node:2191) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): CordovaError: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater
(node:2191) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
[23:27:26]  lint finished in 3.77 s
```

What to change? How to set 1.8 JDK to ionic ?

Comment: What does it show if you type java -version?

Comment: @Ivas it shows version 1.8

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but I would like to share how I solved this incase it might help others in the future.

I had both java 1.8 and the latest 14.0.2.

I solved this on Mac OS by setting the java_home version to 1.8

```
  # Create a JAVA_HOME variable, determined dynamically
  export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)
  # Add that to the global PATH variable
  export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH
```

Then `source ~/.bash_profile` and `java -version`

Output:
`java version "1.8.0_271"`

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to both ~/.profile and ~/.bashrc (/etc/bashrc, then ~/.bashrc) for your USER:

```
export IDEA_SDK=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)
```